# React Native linking out to photo app

Tags: video, react-native, deep-linking

I have made my own video app similar to androids camera and when a user clicks on a past video thumbnail in the bottom corner I want to open the native Photos app.  It is called photos in both cases. I know that I need to do something like this

```
Linking.canOpenURL(photos//app:).then(supported => {
  if (!supported) {
    console.log('Can\'t handle url: ' + url);
  } else {
    return Linking.openURL(url);
  }
  }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```

but what I can't figure out is what should the URL be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use package name "com.google.android.apps.photos"

Your code would look like

```
private final static STRING PHOTOS_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.google.android.apps.photos";
// ...
getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(PHOTOS_PACKAGE_NAME, 0);
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(PHOTOS_PACKAGE_NAME);
if (intent != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    // LOG Error and navigate to Play Store?
}
```